# Running a query over all entities in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a base class for all entities:

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    bool Flagged { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : Entity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : Entity
{
    int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

I want to find all entities where `Flagged` is set to true, and then either modify them or remove them from the database. How do I do this without manually going over every `DbSet` for every derived type?

Comment: How to do Delete I know. But what you want to update in every DbSet?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The actual use case is about entities that are created as a preview for the user (and flagged as such). When the user is done they can decide to apply the preview and make it final (Update the preview flags) or toss it out (Delete all entities flagged as preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with for updating the entities uses `DbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes()` to get all entity types, and `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` to get the `DbSet` of each entity type. Finally cast them to `IQueryable<Entity>` so I can access the entity without knowing the underlying type of the `DbSet`.

Using that I made the following extension methods:

```
public static IQueryable<Entity> GetEntityQuery(this DbContext context, Type entityType)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(DbContext).GetMethod(nameof(DbContext.Set));
    MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
    var dbSet = genericMethod.Invoke(context, null);
    return (IQueryable<Entity>)dbSet;
}

public static IEnumerable<IQueryable<Entity>> GetAllEntityQueries(this DbContext context)
{
    foreach (var entityType in context.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        yield return context.GetEntityQuery(entityType.ClrType);
    }
}
```

For deleting I simply use the `DbContext.Remove` and `DbContext.RemoveRange` methods that take an `object`.